# Loop and Insert monthly schedule by PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm working on loan monthly schedule right now and I met a problem with generate monthly schedule with php and mysql.
My problem is: 
Example: loan date = 2/12/2015,   duration = 5 month
I don't know how to insert to database like this:

```html
<table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpading='0'>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
     <th>Date</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>1st month</th>
     <th>2/12/2015</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2nd month</th>
     <th>3/12/2015</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>3rd month</th>
     <th>4/12/2015</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>4th month</th>
     <th>5/12/2015</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>5th month</th>
     <th>6/12/2015</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>6th month</th>
     <th>7/12/2015</th>
  </tr>
<table>
```

Comment: So you want to insert all 6 date values in the database? Why not just insert the first and the duration/last month and generate the rest when you need them?

Comment: this is HTML fragment? do you plan to insert HTML in database? what is your table structure? where is your code to connect to database and insert query?

Answer (score 0):

In this query add next month from your timestamp value you can adjust this based on your duration try this

```
INSERT INTO `tbl_book`(`book_date`) VALUES (now( ) + INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```