# In mysql how to use increment i=1, i++?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, mysqli

```html
<table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpading='0'>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
     <th>Date</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>1st month</th>
     <th>2/12/2014</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2nd month</th>
     <th>2/1/2015</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>3rd month</th>
     <th>2/2/2015</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>4th month</th>
     <th>2/3/2015</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>5th month</th>
     <th>2/4/2015</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>6th month</th>
     <th>2/5/2015</th>
  </tr>
<table>
```

I have user below query which add next month only i'm expection how to increment one value in mysql ?

INSERT INTO `tbl_book`(`book_date`) VALUES (now( ) + INTERVAL 1 MONTH)

i'm expecting single query to below table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plan A:  Write a Stored Procedure with a loop and a counter.

Plan B:  Create a table of integers, SELECT from table, stop at 6, and use the integer in the date arithmetic:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_book (book_date)
    SELECT CURDATE() + INTERVAL n MONTH
        FROM integers
        WHERE n BETWEEN 1 AND 6;
```

Comment: I don't know stored procedure give some example ?

Comment: You are asking and giving answers? Hoping that someone would get on hook to value answer or something?
[Seems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28641741/loop-and-insert-monthly-schedule-by-php) like Lazy Developer is clon.
This question is put here 90 minutes after first one.

Answer (score 0):

Use the dateadd function of mysql.

```
DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL expr type)
```

You would want the Interval to be "MONTH"

```
INSERT INTO tbl_book(book_date) VALUES (date_add(now( ), INTERVAL 1 Month);
```

You can find more details at http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/date_add.php

Comment: which in insert one row i'm expection above table one i run add 6 row like table use only query not php